# Howto request nested resources using RESTkit for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, restkit

I have a clean RESTful API that provides me with the following endpoints

/vendors
/vendors/:id/countries
/vendors/:id/countries/:id/cities

I am inexperienced when it comes to Objective-C and RESTkit. Just in the moment I am looking for a way to map the server side objects to 3 classes on client side: vendor, country, city.

So I'd expect a declaration for every class that

a) defines the endpoint where the JSON objects can be fetched
b) defines the 1:n relationships from vendor to country and from country to city.

After doing so, I'd expect to be able to do something like that [pseudocode]:

```
vendors = Vendors.all //retrieve all vendors and construct objects
countries = vendors[0].countries  //retrieve all countries of the first vendor
city = countries.last.cities //retrieve the cities of the last countries
```

Unfortunately I do not see something like that in RESTkit. To be able to create relations between objects, the API would have to deliver nested resources! For example a call to the countries endpoint would have to deliver the related vendor object directly within the countries JSON?!?

This is something that I do not understand at all. In that case I'd use every kind of legacy protocol and did not have to use a RESTful API.

Do I overlook something? Can anyone help on this topic or provide a link to a resource explaining RESTkit in more detail than the docs do?

Answer (score 0):

The RestKit Documentation has a section: Mapping without KVC which covers this.

> RKPathMatcher: The path matcher evaluates URL patterns to produce
>   matches with patterns such as '/articles/:articleID', which would
>   match against '/articles/1234' or '/articles/some-great-article'.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#mapping-without-kvc

Note: I haven't tried this yet but the doc seems to be updated for the latest version of RestKit (0.20.0)

Answer (score -2):

Answering your question, yes, you can define relationships using RestKit and the JSON representation needs to be nested, read forward to see an example of this and how to map it on your objects.

You have to follow this steps:

1. Create your objects using the properties that you get from the API.
2. You need to set the mappings associated to each one of your objects
   and the JSON/XML that you get from the API.
3. Define the mappings between your objects if a property of an object is another object.

From the [Object Mapping Documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md):

Need to parse the following JSON:

```
{ "articles": [
    { "title": "RestKit Object Mapping Intro",
      "body": "This article details how to use RestKit object mapping...",
      "author": {
          "name": "Blake Watters",
          "email": "blake@restkit.org"
      },
      "publication_date": "7/4/2011"
    }]
}
```

Define your objects in Objective-c:

```
//author.h
@interface Author : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* email;
@end

//article.h
@interface Article : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* title;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* body;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Author* author; //Here we use the author object!
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate*   publicationDate;
@end
```

Set the mappings:

```
// Create our new Author mapping
RKObjectMapping* authorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Author class]];
// NOTE: When your source and destination key paths are symmetrical, you can use mapAttributes: as a shortcut
[authorMapping mapAttributes:@"name", @"email", nil];

// Now configure the Article mapping
RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class]];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"title" toAttribute:@"title"];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"body" toAttribute:@"body"];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"author" toAttribute:@"author"];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"publication_date" toAttribute:@"publicationDate"];

// Define the relationship mapping
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"author" toRelationship:@"author" withMapping:authorMapping];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:articleMapping forKeyPath:@"articles"];
```

I hope this can be useful to you!

Comment: Question was about delivering of the nested resources, not about mapping.